# Don't know exactly what jta-data-source should be

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jta

I tried to get Spring-MVC, Hibernate, JTA with a Postgres Server to work.

I got most of the stuff working (Read from Db through EntityManager without JTA), but I can't get the transactions to work with JTA.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>???</jta-data-source>
    <class>net.test.test.database.UsersEntity</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="validpw"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

If I provide my datasource from my servlet I get an Exception like

```
DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'dataSource'
```

I also found resources saying the datasource should be defined in the application-server (but I am not sure about this one). If it is important I use a Tomcat-server.

Comment: Tomcat doesn't come with JTA support. You'll have to use a full-JEE server like JBoss or WebLogic or Glasshfish to have JTA (or use an XA transaction manager like Bitronix). But do you really need JTA? Do you intend to have transactions spanning multiple databases or JMS services?

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was the problem. I switched to Glassfish and now I don't get this Error anymore :) I Pobably don't need JTA, but this is just a Test-Project and its purpose is to get to know those Libraries. Just want to play around. I got another problem now. When I execute em.persist(user); It is not saved into the database at all. When it is executed the next time I get an error: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [net.test.test.database.UsersEntity#0]. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: No, not without knowing more details (code, configuration, transactional handling, etc.)

Comment: Ok no problem. As I said em.persist enclosed in a Transactional Annotation is all the code. (NOTE: non-write stuff like find() Works).  Which configuration should I provide, that heplps you?

Comment: If I execute the command: 

        UsersEntity u = em.find(UsersEntity.class, 1l);
        u.setName(u.getName() + "-");

The u.getName() gets an additional line every iteration, but the database stays without any additionals lines. I cannot do any changes in the database. If I try to commit it I get the following Error: Cannot execute getTransaction() on a container-managed EntityManager. How can I get my application to commit my changes and persist it into my db?

Comment: Spring is probably not configured to use the container's transaction manager.

Comment: Hmmm. Probably. I will stop using JTA as I don't need it anyway. But still, thanks a lot for your help